# How to nake a Discussion forum or Q&A forum?

Tags: javascript, php, html

"Iam creating website for youngsters, but i want to add a discussion and Q&A forum at site. how can attach those facilities in my website?"

Comment: Solid question here folks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need a remote database to do so, the front end is going to be something you have to implement yourself. If you are new to databases I would advise looking into *Cloud* solutions like Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/). There are tons of content online to get you started.